# Zend Debugger Eclipse Startup Error: eclipse.php.debug.core was unable to load class debug.core.model.PHPConditionalBreakpoint

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I work on Mac OSX Lion and ever since I've installed the Zend Debugger and gotten it to be able to debug php web applications, I often encounter this Eclipse startup error:

> Error creation extension for extension-point
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.daemon.communication Plug-in
>   org.eclipse.php.debug.core was unable to load class
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.zend.communication.DebuggerCommunicationDaemon.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.php.debug.core (258).

The error log contains the following stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: Plug-in org.eclipse.php.debug.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.model.PHPConditionalBreakpoint.  
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.BreakpointManager.createBreakpoint(BreakpointManager.java:554
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.BreakpointManager.loadBreakpoints(BreakpointManager.java:264
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.BreakpointManager.initializeBreakpoints(BreakpointManager.java:449)  
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.BreakpointManager.getBreakpoints0(BreakpointManager.java:418)    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.BreakpointManager.start(BreakpointManager.java:408)  
at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.start(DebugPlugin.java:682)   
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
... Omitted for brevity ...
```

This error often goes away when I just restart eclipse a few times. I've googled for solutions and tried reinstalling eclipse a couple of times. This error only seems to occur if I have both ADT (Android Development Tools) and PDT (PHP Development Tools) + Zend Debugger installed.

Please let me know if you have information about how to solve this problem. On a related note, I never really got the PDT + Zend debugger to work (as in debug) PHP apps on Windows.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but without the ADT - PDT & Zend on Windows just don't seem to play well with each other.

Comment: @JMax I haven't been able to resolve it yet.

Comment: @JimBeam I never got this to work on windows anyway. If you're able to resolve it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround instead of a solution, but so far, it's going good:

I downloaded and installed `Eclipse for PHP Developers`(aka Zend Eclipse PDT) version 3.0.2 from [Zend](http://www.zend.com/community/pdt/downloads) website and I'm now able to debug Wordpress and Joomla, both pretty complicated projects as far as PHP goes.

I will update if I experience a problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, I now have two instances of eclipse on my machine - one with ADT and another with PDT.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (yours came up top of Google when I pasted my error message) after a few similar and different errors I decided to check my Eclipse workspace settings after an alternative workspace of mine worked and debugged fine.

It turns out my PHP executable pathway was empty (after having previously set it), so I added it back in. No problems so far.

(i.e. here...) Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> PHP Executables -> Add/replace/reselect here.

UPDATE:
sometimes the simplest thing is to select 'Skip all breakpoints' under the 'Breakpoints' view (which opens in debug perspective). Then restart Eclipse. I have had similar error messages since first answering and that usually does the job (of course you can deselect 'Skip all breakpoints' after that from the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error a few times, even in the Zend Eclipse PHP version.  It only seems to happen when two things are true:

1) The "breakpoints" view is visible on eclipse start (that is, you can see where breakpoints would be listed)

and

2) The file open and active in the editor is NOT a PHP file

For example, I got this repeatably with a CSS file open in the editor on the debug perspective with the breakpoints tab active.

To get around it: Start eclipse and ignore the bug about loading the plugin (for now).  Make a PHP file the active document in the editor, and change from the debug perspective to the PHP perspective.  Close eclipse and restart.  On restart, the error should be gone and debugging should be active again.

I can't guarantee this is the solution everytime, but I can reliably replicate this failure (and solution) with the breakpoint/non-PHP conditions described above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04 and I received this error after installing Java 7. My PDT settings which used to work stop working. My solution was to uninstall PDT and reinstall it. I am not sure if this is relevant to your question but it might solve the issue.

Help -> About eclipse platform

click "Installation details" button

click php development tools (PDT) sdk feature

click uninstall

follow prompts

reinstall pdt in the normal way

My previous debug launches were deleted but my old project was left untouched. I re-ran a debug from Run -> Debug Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever gotten this after closing down an Eclipse php project that I've enabled various breakpoints in.

My workaround is once the project opens and I get the error message I select `skip all breakpoints`, close the project and re-open it. I then deselect the skip breakpoints and start working. The error, at least in my case happens randomly and for no other reason than I closed the project with breakpoints enabled.

Wish I had a more technical solution or fix but I decided my time was better spent working on actual work than chasing this deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened when I closed Eclipse while a project was still running in debug mode.
I did more or less the same as @rahvin_t to fix it.

Run > Skip all breakpoint. Close Eclipse, start eclipse and I could start the project again.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few errors that happen on start-up similar to this one. They seem to occur when there are 'unusual' files open in the editor (e.g. css or javascript)

What usually works for me:

1. Close all your files in Eclipse (Ctrl+Shift+W)
2. Restart Eclipse.