# Eclipse cannot debug PHP

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I use XAMPP, PHP version 8.2.4, PDT version 8.0.0, Xdebug is downloaded from https://odan.github.io/2020/12/03/xampp-xdebug-setup-php8.html and choose PHP 8.2 (64-Bit) link.

When I want to start the PHP built-in server in debug mode, an error is shown:

> An internal error occurred during: "Creating console for C:\xampp\php\php.exe (2 Dec 2023, 10:04:57 pm)".
> class org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.PHPProcess (org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @714720ab; org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.PHPProcess is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @57beeb5d)

But it’s all OK if started in non-debug mode.

My php.ini Xdebug section is as follow:

```ini
[XDebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735158/zend-debugger-eclipse-startup-error-eclipse-php-debug-core-was-unable-to-load-c